# A question on the Banach fixed point theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Suppose $f:(X,\tilde{d})\rightarrow(X,d)$ be a continuous function satisfying \begin{eqnarray}d(f(x),f(y))\leq \lambda d(x,y),\end{eqnarray} $\lambda > 1$. Let $\tilde{d}(x,y)=\lambda d(x,y)$. I observed that the topologies due to $d$ and $\tilde{d}$ are equivalent. Hence the "contraction" condition now reads as \begin{eqnarray}d(f(x),f(y))\leq \tilde{d}(x,y).\end{eqnarray} Can it concluded form here that a fixed point exists for $f$?. In other words I was wondering whether the Banach fixed point theorem holds if the metrics in the domain and the range spaces are equivalent and not exactly the same?.

Comment: In Banach fixed point theorem $0<\lambda <1$.

Comment: That's true but I have accordingly changed my metric. Please read my question in the final sentence. @S.Panja

Comment: So,    I think , from your last equation $d(f(x),f(y))\le \bar d(x,y)$ we can not conclude $f$ has a fixed point.

Comment: If $d$ and $\bar d$ are equivalent then it need not be true that $f$ has a fixed point

Comment: This theorem "lives" in the world  or category of geometry, not of topology, but good question.

Comment: @Alexander: But your equation relating d and d-hat does not satisfy the conditions of the fixed point thm.

Comment: I am not sure, but you need the **same** metric on the domain and codomain. So you can't just scale the metric of the codomain. otherwise every square matrix has a fix point and thus 1 as eigenvalue!

Answer (score 1):

You certainly have to account for the factor occuring in the equivalence. That is, if you merely have $d\circ f\le \tilde d$, then you do don't have a contraction unless you know that $\tilde d\le \lambda d $with some $\lambda<1$. For example $f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, $x\mapsto x+1$ has no fixed points, but you can certainly find that the inequality holds if you use different metrics (i.e., different multiples of $|x-y|$).

Comment: Thanks to all. @Hagen con Eitzen...How about writing $\lambda=\mu\frac{\lambda}{\mu}$ where $0 \leq \mu <1$ and consider $\tilde{d}(x,y)=\frac{\lambda}{\mu}d(x,y)$?. Can this account for the factor occurring in the equivalence?.